# Experiment to test flatness of prism

Tags: optics, experimental-physics, geometric-optics

I have a Prism glued to a prism plate. Let's say the method of using optical glue is good enough, and minimal human error is tolerated. What experiment would be a good to check if the prism is not tilted to one side (flatness deviation) beyond certain threshold.

The prism is a retro-reflecting dispersing [prism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Littrow_prism). So my idea is to shoot a collimated laser beam and across the reflective surface and see the deviation of reflected beam.

Any other ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a sodium lamp positioned above the prism and slightly to the side to create a reflection at the interface. Look for interference patterns at the prism/prism plate interface. If the spacing between dark fringes is small (and you have many fringes), you have a problem.  If  you have very few fringes and the spacing is large, the interface is close to being flat.

Comment: This would be a good idea for quick estimation. If I want a quantitative result (for eg conduct the same experiment over 100 such cases) then its better to have a experimental data to compare and form a toleration point.

Comment: Wouldn't the spacing between the fringes be quantitative?

Comment: Yes, adjacent fringes indicate a spacing change of $\lambda$/4, unless the phase shift at the bottom reflection is different from the top reflection.

Comment: Can this minimization of phase shift between bottom and top be carried out analytically ? Any references you could provide for the same ?

Comment: Any good intermediate optics text should discuss this. Jenkins & White is the classic standard.